# How do I get part of a URL and redirect the user to a URL with that part of the URL in?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a bookmark that runs javascript.
It will get part of a URL from a game's forum that I use and take the user to an edit page for it.

The url for the post could be something like this for example - http://www.roblox.com/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=78212279

Did you see the PostID bit? I want to get that number and redirect the user to this:
http://www.roblox.com/Forum/EditPost.aspx?PostID=[NUMBER GOES HERE]

So I want to get a part of the url and put it in the PostID.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Javascript :

```
document.location = document.location.href.replace('ShowPost', 'EditPost');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your bookmarklet:

```
<a href="javascript:location.href='EditPost.aspx'+location.search" onclick="alert('Drag this to your bookmarks bar');">Edit Post</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The querystring of a URL is available via `window.location.search`. So, if you are on the page `http://www.roblox.com/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=78212279`

```
var query = location.search; // ?PostID=78212279
```

Now we need to split the query string into key value pairs. Each key value pair is delimited by `&` and each key and value within a pair is delimited by `=`. We also need to take into account that key value pairs are encoded in the query string too. Here's a function that will take care of all of this for us and return an object whose properties represent the key value pairs in a query string

```
function getQueryString() {
    var result = {},
        query= location.search.substr(1).split('&'),
        len = query.length,
        keyValue = [];

    while (len--) {
        keyValue = query[len].split('=');

        if (keyValue[1].length) {
            result[decodeURIComponent(keyValue[0])] = decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now using this on the page in question, we can get the `PostID` in the query string

```
var query = getQueryString();

query.PostID; // 78212279
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression.

```
var re = /^https?:\/\/.+?\?.*?PostID=(\d+)/;

function getPostId(url) {
    var matches = re.exec(url);
    return matches ? matches[1] : null;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/Axd3r/)**